# Online Anti-Virus service

Tags: web-services, antivirus

How would it be possible to design an online-antivirus service. I was thinking about creating an online version of some open-source antivirus. Would it be possible to upload something like a binary image of the selected folders, and then pass that as an argument to the antivirus service installed on the web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.virustotal.com - this is how they do it. BTW - hashing previous results would probably save you a lot of time on scanning duplicate requests.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Be quicker to have them fedex their hard drive, though.